# Horizontal 'limit' line in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Is it possibile to add a horizontal line to an existing chart in [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)?

Here the example char code:

```
// the canvas
<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="200"></canvas>

// the js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data);
```

I want to add a horizontal marker line (eg. at y=100 like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/hXDYh/2/) for highcharts)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can actually do that. You want the horizontal marker line so you need to add this code inside your y-axis

```
plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 2,
            value: .50 * 200 // The marker value will be 100
                             // Or you can just set its value to 100
}]
```

Comment: This looks like Highchart.js, like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553051/chart-js-how-to-add-a-line-in-the-canvas-for-bar-chart
How does this work in chart.js?

Comment: Sorry bout that. I've found no way to do this in chart.js. If nothing shows up with the correct one. Better use highcharts if you want to achieve that limit line.

Comment: Me neither, that was the issue why I've asked this question ;) Have to use chart.js in this case. But thanks for your help